# Is there a "fastest way" to construct Strings in Java?

Tags: java, string

I normally create a String in Java the following way:

```
String foo = "123456";
```

However, My lecturer has insisted to me that forming a String using the `format` method, as so:

```
String foo = String.format("%s", 123456);
```

Is much faster.

Also, he says that using the StringBuilder class is even faster.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String foo = sb.append(String.format("%s", 123456)).toString();
```

Which is the fastest method to create a String, **if there even is one**?

*They could not be 100% accurate as I might not remember them fully.*

Comment: Good question, is this autoboxing? I know that Integer foo = 1 is slower than Integer foo = Integer.valueOf(1);

Comment: Being a student, it would be great if you can think of a way to test his theory. Can you write a Java class that would construct 100000 strings/stringbuffers etc. and time it?

Comment: I would tell your professor that in the real world the very very very small possible performance advantage is far outweighed by readability.  Furthermore, code should always be written to work first, as simple and easily as possible, and then optimized IF there's a need (which usually there isn't).

Comment: Consistently obscuring code to have the quickest String creation isn't worth it in my oppinion. Also, what way of, at least concatenating,  Strings are the quickest have changed from java version to java version, so your careful optimizations might blow up in your face when upgrading. I'm sure a lot of very efficiently running code have their Strings initialized like your first example, so I suggest you continue initializing them that way.

Comment: Did you say your Professor? that's right, you mean the guy whose never written a line of production code? you mean him? yeah? the one how couldn't get a job so he decided to teach? do I have the right guy?

Comment: I agree 100% with favoring developer performance (readability) over software performance (micro-optimization). However, your teacher is wrong anyway. How could creating a new String from a String via several method calls possibly be faster than just referencing a String instance already in the constant pool?

Comment: 2 lines of code: 3 objects being created (if I counted correctly), 4 methods being called, one autoboxing (+1 object, +1 method) and STILL using another constant String `"%s"` is MUCH faster than just using a constant String?

Comment: @Trick, `Integer foo = 1` is actually just syntactic sugar for `Integer foo = Integer.valueOf(1)`. The compiled class files will look the same.

Comment: What is it about instructors teaching bad software practices? I've seem this in other posts.

Comment: Was he talking about building Strings in a loop, or *every* String instance?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If there is only one string then:

```
String foo = "123456";
```

Is fastest. You'll notice that the `String.format` line includes `"%s"` in it, so I don't see how the lecturer could possibly think that was faster. Plus you've got a method call on top of it.

However, if you're building a string over time, such as in a for-loop, then you'll want to use a StringBuilder. If you were to just use `+=` then you're building a brand new string *every time* the `+=` line is called. StringBuilder is much faster since it holds a buffer and appends to that every time you call `append`.

Comment: Yeah, if you're declaring a string literal, then just embedding it is obviously the fastest way. I had a programming language prof once tell the class that Java didn't have pointers, so you couldn't create things like linked lists, he thought all the java collections were implemented in C or something. I had another lecturer say that 'secure' websites were ones that ended in '.shtml' (rather then starting with https) Sometimes they just don't know what they're talking about

Comment: Plus in a tight loop you could be creating a HUGE number of strings each one a little bigger than the last.

This is true in C# (well .Net) as well.

I also agree with the comment from Eric Wendelin that you should write a test to see. Don't tell your prof the opinions of people on teh interwebz when you could show him documented proof of whether he is right or wrong. I would do a number of test cases: speed to create one string via each method, speed to create lots in a loop, etc.

Comment: @jeffa00: I agree, instrumented testing is the best way to prove this. However, beware as professors (in my experience anyway) don't like to be challenged. *Especially* don't do it in class.

Comment: If you have many occurrences of "123456" then they all refer to the same intern()-ed value.  But if you run String.format() on multiple "123456" you generate duplicate copies.

Answer (score 14):

Slightly off-topic, but I wish that the whole "must-not-use-plus-to-concatenate-strings-in-Java" myth would go away. While it might have been true in early versions of Java that StringBuffer was faster and "+ was evil", it is certainly not true in modern JVMs that are taking care of a lot of optimisations.

For example, which is faster?

```
String s = "abc" + "def";
```

or

```
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    buf.append("abc");
    buf.append("def");
    String s = buf.toString();
```

The answer is the former. The JVM recognises that this is a string constant and will actually put "abcdef" in the string pool, whereas the "optimised stringbuffer" version will cause an extra StringBuffer object to be built.

Another JVM optimisation is

```
String s = onestring + " concat " + anotherstring;
```

Where the JVM will work out what the best way of concatenating will be. In JDK 5, this means a StringBuilder will be internally used and it will be faster than using a string buffer.

But as other answers have said, the "123456" constant in your question is certainly the fastest way and your lecturer should go back to being a student :-)

And yes, I've been sad enough to verify this by looking at the Java bytecode...

Comment: More Gyaan to your "Slightly off-topic" comment. In another scenario, creating Strings using StringBuilder would be more efficient.

If you are concatenating different strings via for loop, which is generally the case like

        String simple = "";
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 100000; counter++) {
            simple += counter;
        }
// This simple op took around 12 sec to complete.

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 100000; counter++) {
            buffer.append(buffer);
        }
// This took only 14 ms!

Comment: Oops, I just realized I am emphasing part2 or jasonh answer.

Answer (score 11):

This whole discussion is moot. Please read this article by Jeff, i.e., the guy who created Stack Overflow.

[The Sad Tragedy of Micro-Optimization Theater](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001218.html)

Please refer your instructor to this post and ask him to stop ruining his/her student's brains with useless information.  Algorithmic optimizations are where your code will live or die, not with what method you use to construct strings.  In any case, StringBuilder, and String formatter have to execute ACTUAL CODE with REAL MEMORY, if you just construct a string it gets set aside during compile time and is ready to be used when you need it, in essence, it has 0 run-time cost, while the other options have real cost, since code actually needs to be executed.

Comment: Not to get too picky, but I think you mean to say that the discussion is "moot". Although it is "mute" too since SO doesn't have sounds... ;)

Comment: Let's micro-optimize this post! :)

Comment: If the OP had a too-slow program and tried to optimize it by looking at trivial string concatenations, I might have agreed with you, but this is a question where the OP wonders how something works. Saying "don't optimize until you need it" to someone who is trying to learn about their programming platform is like saying "don't bother buying an insurance until your house is on fire". (As for the rest of your post, I agree fully.)

Answer (score 8):

```
String foo = "some string literal";
```

Is certainly the fastest way to make a String. It's embedded in the .class file and is a simple memory look-up to retrieve.

Using `String.format` when you have nothing to really format just looks ugly and might cause junior developers to cry.

If the String is going to be modified, then `StringBuilder` is the best since `Strings` are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Comment: Using String.format when you have nothing to really format would probably also cause senior developers to cry, too.

Answer (score 5):

In your second example, using:

```
String foo = String.format("%s", 123456);
```

doesn't buy you anything; 123456 is already a constant value, so why not just assign foo = "123456"? For constant strings, there's no better way.

If you're creating a string from multiple parts being appended together at runtime, use StringBuffer or StringBuilder (the former being thread-safe).

Answer (score 4):

If your string is known at compile-time, then using a literal is best: `String foo = "123456";`.

If your string is not known at compile-time and is composed of an aggregation of smaller strings, `StringBuilder` is usually the way to go (but beware thread-safety!).

Using `String foo = String.format("%s", 123456);` **could** reduce your .class' size and make class-loading it a tiny bit faster, but that would be extremely aggressive (extreme) memory tuning there ^^.

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out, if you're just building a single string with no concatenation, just use String.

For concatenating multiple bits into one big string, StringBuffer is slower than StringBuilder, but StringBuffer is synchronized.  If you don't need synchronization, StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

Are you 100% certain that the instructor was not talking about something like:

```
String foo = "" + 123456;
```

I see my students do that type of thing "all the time" (a handful will do that each term).  The reason that they do it is that some book showed them how to do it that way.  Shakes head and fist at lazy book writers!

Comment: I thought it's idiomatic shortcut for `foo = String.valueOf(int_var)`. I guess there is some overhead for creating (reference to) empty string, but beside this, what's wrong with it ?

Comment: It is not the clearest thing to do.  Also String.valueOf(int) calls Integer.toString(int) (not a requirement, but that is what the JDK does).  If the compiler does that then it'll be slower, depending on the environment, than calling Integer.toString(int).  Integer.toString(int) is clearer, to me, than "" + int and more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The first example you gave is the fastest and the simplest.  Use that.

Each piece of code you added in those examples makes it significantly slower and more difficult to read.

I would suggest example 2 is at least 10-100x slower than example 1 and example 3 is about 2x slower than example 2.

Did your processor provide any justification for this assertion?

BTW: Your first example doesn't construct a String at all (which is why it is fastest), it just hands you a String sitting in the String constant pool.

Answer (score 0):

How about measuring dynamic strings so that VM cannot optimise it:

```
public static void measureConcats(long lim){
double sum = 0;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(long a = 0;a<lim;++a){
    sum+=Math.random();
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Sum:" +sum);
System.out.println("Double creations time:" + (end - start));

String res = "";
Double sad = 0.0;
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(long b = 0;b<lim;++b){
    sad = Math.random();
    String sa = sad.toString();
    res+=sa;
}
end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Pure string concat time:" + (end - start));
System.out.println("len:"+res.length());

StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(long c = 0;c<lim;++c){
    sad = Math.random();
    String sa = sad.toString();
    sbf.append(sa);
}
end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("StringBuffer concat time:" + (end - start));
System.out.println("len:"+sbf.length());}
```

My result for 10000 concats is 364ms for String+=String and 14ms for StringBuffer append.
I was very surprised about this result.