# String s = "a" + "b" + "c"; Can anyone tell for this statement how many object will be created

Tags: java, string

Code:

```
String s = "a" + "b" + "c";
```

I want to know how many objects will be created for this statement.

Comment: Please read all the related questions and answers.

Comment: This might actually be implementation-dependent.

Comment: Actually the answer to the duplicate is not correct.

Comment: @arshajii it would be more helpful to explain that over there, as a comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard This is actually specified by the JLS, see the link in my answer.

Comment: +1 because this question has value in that the accepted answer to the duplicated question is incorrect and simply taking the answer to that question, rather than re-asking, would have perpetuated incorrect information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be one string object in the string pool. `"a" + "b" + "c"` is resolved to `"abc"` at compile time (see [JLS §15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)), so what you have is equivalent to

```
String s = "abc";
```

There are no `StringBuilder`s involved here, contrary to what the accepted answer of the duplicate question asserts. You can even see this in the bytecode:

```
LDC "abc"
ASTORE 1
```

From the JLS link above:

> Compile-time constant expressions of type `String` are always "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.