# Object for the String

Tags: java, string, object

How many object will be created for this syntax
`String a="b" +"c" +"d";`
I tried asking with different people some say it will create 4 object some say 1 object.

Comment: Read the byte code. But it has been said, that a StringBuilder is used, so it might be 1 + 1 = 2

Comment: This is probably a misconception. If those single Strings were dynamic rather than constant, this would indeed be a little bit inefficient and a StringBuilder should be used. For constants the compiler is smart enough to optimize it by itself. (Don't worry about Strings too much...your application will most likely have much worse bottlenecks.)

Comment: Also depends if that string has been encountered previously and so is interned

Answer (score 0):

**Only one!**

Expression `String a="b" +"c" +"d";` is a compile time constant and after compilation you will just have one String instance and that is `"bcd"`

Answer (score 0):

For a constant concatenation: only the resulting String.

If there are String variables involved, a StringBuilder is new-ed and then everything appended, so the second object is the resulting String.

Answer (score 0):

One!

Since your creating ONE String object, "b","c","d" are constants, the compiler won't allocate a space for them on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The jls spec clearly [states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) that 1 `String` will result as a result of a constant expression.

That still results in more than one object, as the `String` itself is composed of a `char[]`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are correct. I found the relative jls spec and corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**One** object will be created! 
String a="b" +"c" +"d"; bcd will show up at the class constant pool .(literal object)**[awesome answer by fellow stackoverflow member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878496/string-s-a-b-c-can-anyone-tell-for-this-statement-how-many-object-w)**

You can even see this in the bytecode:

```
LDC "bcd"
ASTORE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One object will be created at the constant pool