# How many String objects will be created in String s="abc"+"xyz"; in prior versions of Java 1.5?

Tags: java, string

As per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578133/how-many-java-string-objects-will-be-created-in-the-statement-string-s-abcxy) , in java versions 1.5 onward  in code `String s="abc"+"xyz";`  only one object is created due to compiler optimization using StringBuilder class.

```
new StringBuilder().append(abc).append(xyz).toString()
```

So does that mean before java 1.5 String used to create three objects one "abc"  ,another "xyz" and the third one "abcxyz" OR then it use some other class like StringBuffer for similar compiler optimization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as far as I'm aware that has *always* been treated as a compile-time constant, and has always been equivalent to

```
String s = "abcxyz";
```

Note that Java 1.5 introduced `StringBuilder`; before that execution-time string concatenation used `StringBuffer`.

Looking at the [first edition of the JLS](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/3.doc.html#101083), already the crucial sentence existed:

> String literals - **or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.27)** are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern (§20.12.47).

(And section 15.27 includes string concatenation.)

Answer (score 4):

The code

```
String s="abc"+"xyz";
```

creates one String literal at compile time.  Java has always done this.  It did not change in Java 5.0.

What did change is that if you have code like this

```
String abc = "abc";
String s = abc + "xyz";
```

In Java 1.0 to 1.4 it used StringBuffer to do this.  It was replaced in Java 5.0 with StringBuilder as it is more efficient if you don't need thread safety and in 99.9% of cases, you don't.

Comment: (And in 100% of cases where the concatenation is happening in an expression like this, you don't.)

Comment: @DavidConrad slightly worse than that is that StringBuffer is only thread safe for one only one operation. Multiple calls require you to lock the buffer externally.