# Java - How to format an SQL statement without getting hit by Java's String immutability?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

For example I want to create the following SQL SELECT statement for readability in JDBC:

```
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(
        "SELECT " +
            "table1.*, " +
            "table2.someColumn " +
        "FROM " +
            "table1 " +
        "LEFT JOIN " +
            "table2 " +
        "ON " +
            "table1.column1 = table2.column2 " +
        "WHERE " +
            "date > today");
```

Basically by formatting the SQL command, especially longer ones, it makes it easier to read when coding. The downside is that each line is an instance of an immutable String and this will have a performance and memory penalty. ***Yes I could use StringBuffer but this makes the SQL code once again unreadable, the same as if I had one big long SQL line.***

And yes in this case the cost is only once, but in some cases I have parameters that need to be included. Adding "?" is great, and again minimizes the String immutable issue, but in some cases the SQL command is generated dynamically and this will result in slightly different SQL commands (where parameters are not possible).

Is there a way to write this code within Java and keep the code formatted without paying the String immutability penalty (and without using StringBuffer).

Note: I also can't write it to a file because of other reasons which I won't go into here.

Comment: Why are you worried -- the above is all literal data.  The compiler will generate a single literal string.

Comment: If you are worried about the performance impact on concatenating strings you are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: In Java, this is always treated as a compile time constant. Don't just me, then trust Jon Skeet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526654/how-many-string-objects-will-be-created-in-string-s-abcxyz-in-prior-versio/23526774#23526774

Comment: No, don't trust Skeet himself.  But do trust the excerpt from the JLS that he quoted.

Comment: How about working out whether there's a problem here, before you try to optimise?  It seems to be that this is rather like trying to make your car go faster by wiping the mud off the tyres.

Comment: I did not realize that this had changed in Java 5. What's really weird then is why am I getting different performance values for StringBuffer and litterals. I'll have to look into that some more than because there's something else working here too then :(

Comment: @DavidWallace: Yes of course, I was saying it jokingly and linking to a question today that covers the subject of this question quite well. And I agree with you that this may be one of those "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that behind the scenes, you're getting a StringBuilder / StringBuffer when you use `+` anyway.  Per the official [Javadoc on String:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

> String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method.

Comment: This is true.  Where you really suffer though is if you are concat through a loop where the String is assigned and then transformed again to be appended together.

Comment: Where do you see that + is a StringBuffer? I don't see anything in the Javadocs. And there is definitely a penalty if you test it in a loop. I need performant code because of the scale of what I'm doing.

Comment: In Java 1.5 and later compiler optimization used `StringBuilder`. Prior to that it used `StringBuilder`. It will always be one string literal at compile time.

Comment: OP didn't ask for more 'interesting' solutions, but if he had, I'd throw in Antlr's stringtemplate library.  I've used it to solve similar problems with great success, but I can't say it would perform any better than straight string concatenation.  It would definitely be more readable than `StringBuffer.append` over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stringbuffer/stringBuilder and use \n logic to hold formatted string and then use the toString methods to get a String.At the end use a replaceAll to get the string without the line delimiter

```
StringBuffer strBuf=new StringBuffer("");
strBuf.append("SELECT );
strBuf.append("* );
..
```

To display, use strBugf.toString();

When using in the query

```
String Finalquery =strBuf.toString().replaceAll("\n","");;
```

Alternatively , you can also have a list of Strings but I would prefer a strinBuilder/Buffer over a list of Strings.

I really do not understand why you are apprehensive to idea of strigbuffer/ stringBuilder

Comment: As I said in the question, I'm trying to avoid StringBuffer because the added text makes it harder to read and scan ;)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should take care of that but if you want you can make the query string a constant and it will be calculated at compile time with little to no overhead:

```
private static final String QUERY_STRING = "SELECT " +
            "table1.*, " +
            "table2.someColumn " +
        "FROM " +
            "table1 " +
        "LEFT JOIN " +
            "table2 " +
        "ON " +
            "table1.column1 = table2.column2 " +
        "WHERE " +
            "date > today";
```

...

```
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(QUERY_STRING);
```

Comment: To quote the question "but in some cases the SQL command is generated dynamically and this will result in slightly different SQL commands" Therefore I can't make this a constant. And unfortunately no the compiler will not optimize the code as you're suggesting for Strings.

Comment: If you need to modify the query, just use prepared statements (if you only need query parameters) or String.format in case you need something out of the ordinary. In any case the string template is going to be constant.

Comment: " And unfortunately no the compiler will not optimize the code as you're suggesting for Strings" - it will. Google "string externalization"

Comment: I think we are getting all worked up on String concatenation as a performance problem, its seriously NOT.

Comment: String concatenation can be a real performance issue in some cases. In the example above if you have a lot of calls to the query (ie users) then the impact can be very noticeable!! And this is true if you have quite a few queries that are dynamically generated.

Comment: @dimoniy Do you have a specific reference. I have looked at this in the past and run some test cases and there's always been a performance issue. If it's just once it's not a big deal but it can quickly add up if you're not careful.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier at 3.something GHz I would gladly trade readability in code over a nonsensical performance metric applied to string concatenation.  Ever think that your SQL query might be more of a bottleneck?